# How does the floating point?

Tags: binary, decimal

Enter the number in decimal notation and is translated into the form of floating point binary fraction. Help to understand with an example.
Example: Given the number in the decimal number system **-12.56**, translating into a binary system get **-1100.10001111** further converted **-1.10010001111 * 10 ^ 3** For so is it done? The reason I ask [is](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.A1.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B8_.D0.B2.D1.8B.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5) for example for others to do, and I can not understand where does a line highlighted in red.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/199xI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve; anyway remember that you want to multiply by `2^n` and not `10^n` since you are working with binary numbers.

Have a look at my `bc` session below:

```
thomas@thomas-MS-7788:~$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
scale=8
ibase=2
-1100.10001111
-12.55859375
-1.10010001111 * (10)^(11)
-12.55859375000
```

(Here I type `(10)^(11)` for `2^3` since I configured previously the input to be typed in base 2).